# How to give position values for element to align perfectly at all screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, scrollmagic

I am using [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) for animations to happen on scroll.
I'm not really well versed with this, still in the learning process.

So I have a Airplane of which parts are disassembled and come together on scroll and form a Airplane.

For example - the left wing, right wing, plane body, tail, left propeller, right propeller all this parts are separated and coming from different directions to form the plane.

I have managed to make this work at 1366x768 screen resolution. But if I open it at different screen resolution the parts do not assemble at the right position.
http://jsfiddle.net/jv5s6f0j/1/

HTML - (each ID has a background image)

```
<section class="airplane-container">
  <div id="plane-left-wing"></div>
  <div id="plane-right-wing"></div>
  <div id="plane-propeller-left"></div> 
  <div id="plane-propeller-right"></div> 
  <div id="plane-body"></div> 
  <div id="plane-tail"></div> 
</section><!--/airplane-container-->
```

JS-

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var airplane_tween = new TimelineMax()
            .to("#plane-left-wing", 1, {left:"31.2%" , top:"-18%"  },0)
            .to("#plane-right-wing", 1, {right:"31.2%" , top:"-18%"},0)
            .to("#plane-body", 1, {top:"-30%"},0)
            .to("#plane-tail", 1, {top:"-48%" },0.5)
            .to("#plane-propeller-left", 1, {left:"19%" , top:"-22%" },0)
            .to("#plane-propeller-right", 1, {right:"19%" , top:"-22%"},0) ;


var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: ".airplane-container" , duration: 200})
            .setTween(airplane_tween)
            // .setPin("section.airplane-container")
            // .addIndicators({name: "timeline"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)
            .addTo(controller);
```

I tried using percentages instead of fixed px yet doesn't solve the problem.
Please Help!

Comment: You can also optimize your code, maybe put all div out and replace them with img. You are animating DOM element anyway, why animate div with bg image instead of animating just image, change display of image to block just to match div acting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it really depend on approach, as I can't see CSS (maybe put css for this part only) I can't tell much more. Saying this I'll try to explain you my approach with scrollMagic.

1. Make relative container that will hold your absolute elements(don't 
   forget width and height here)
2. Don't use left or right, top or bottom straight forward on absolute
   elements, also DO NOT use '%' that way, it will never fit    your
   needs

Try this (example of left wing):

1. Give it dimensions (width and height, for this example I'll make it
   x and y)
2. Give it left: 50% (this will position a left side of element on
   center)
3. To align it on center assign `margin-left: -x/2` (this will position it to
   center)

Now using this approach, use step 3 (negative margin values) to position elements (NOTE: **do not use  `margin-left: -x/2`**, that will just center it, use the number u need in px values)

And with scroll magic animate just margins

Do the same for top or bottom values

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't really understand how to go about doing this as I'm new to this. This is what I've done as for now http://jsfiddle.net/jv5s6f0j/1/

Comment: I have mentioned the width and height in px. The later stages aren't clear to me :(

Comment: My skype name is zlajaa11 so contact me, I'm at work right now, I'll be more than glad to help you with this, after that I'll write down nice answer with all explanation

Comment: Cool, if you need more help just shoot out :D